# join queryset of dictionary in python by value?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have this queryset -

```
[

   {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia 5ta y 42', 'cantidad': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'b'},
   {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia 5ta y 42', 'cantidad': 2, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'D'}, 
   {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia Habana', 'cantidad': 2, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'D'},
   {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia Pinar del Rio', 'cantidad': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'b'}

]
```

I want this as per the structure described above-

```
 Agencia 5ta y 42  (1,b) (2,D)
 Agencia Habana    (2,D)
 Agencia Pinar del Rio (1,b)
```

I am using python2.7 .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which python version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it work for you?

```
d = [
      {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia 5ta y 42', 'cantidad': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'b'},
      {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia 5ta y 42', 'cantidad': 2, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'D'}, 
      {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia Habana', 'cantidad': 2, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'D'},
      {'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia Pinar del Rio', 'cantidad': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'b'}
    ]

isVisitedAddress = {}

for element in d:
     address = "{0}".format(element.get("estacion__nombre"))
     if address not in isVisitedAddress:
         isVisitedAddress[address] = []
     isVisitedAddress[address].append(
                          [element.get("cantidad") ,element.get("fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador")])

for key in isVisitedAddress.keys():
    finalValue = key
    valuesArray = isVisitedAddress.get(key)
    for values in valuesArray:
        valuekey = ','.join(map(str, values))
        finalValue = "{} ({})".format(finalValue , valuekey)

    print finalValue
```

Output-

```
 Agencia 5ta y 42 (1,b) (2,D)
 Agencia Habana (2,D)
 Agencia Pinar del Rio (1,b)
```

For more check [this](http://ideone.com/sX3aEl)

Comment: Agencia 5ta y 42 has two D and one b.I want join this , in one only dict.Exampe                                                                                                     'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia 5ta y 42', 'cantidad_b': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'b','cantidad_D': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'D',

Comment: Repeat Agencia 5ta y 42 .I do not want to be repeated.
I want to group by Agencia 5ta y 42 .                                                              'estacion__nombre': u'Agencia 5ta y 42', 'cantidad_b': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'b','cantidad_D': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identificador': u'D',

Comment: check my output with the output you want , I have modified my solution ,please check again

Comment: Very Thanks !!!!!!!.tom.  If you can, I'd like to print this
'Station_name': u'Agency 5ta and 42 ',' amount_b ': 1,' fk_codigosm__fk_categoria__identifier ': u'b', 'amount_D': 1, 'fk_codigosm__fk_category__identifier': u'D ','

Comment: little bit of confusing to understand from comments , please create a seperate question and add the link here , thanks